# add two or more large image with thumbnails in one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/425/)

In demo if you hover the thumb large image will fade and change it work what I expect but my problem is, I want more than 1 entry like that in one page, I have no idea when I add another set, the second and the rest of it will be broken.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/426/)**

Can someone explain why this problem arrive even I use `class`

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img").hover(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(".big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to loop through each context (I used `.big-image`) and apply your code each time, using that context:

- Loop using `each()`
- Traverse to large images using `find()`
- Traverse to your thumbnails using `next()` and `find()`
- Store the context in a variable so it can be referenced within your event handler.

```
$(function(){
    $(".big-image").each(function(){
        var $big = $(this);
        $big.find('img').nextAll().hide();
        $big.next('.small-images').find('img').hover(function(e){
            var index = $(this).index();
            $big.find('img').eq(index).show().siblings().hide()
        });
    });
});
```

Note this assumes that `.small-images` will always be an immediate sibling of `.big-image`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/429/)